# Запись в таблицу BigQuery из объекта json

Tags: python, json-encode, bigquery

Пробую записать в таблицу BigQuery объект json полученный через API запрос к сервису. Данные считываются порционно и так же порционно обновляются в таблице. При первой загрузке порции данных из json формируется схема таблицы BigQuery (свойство autoDetect = True по умолчанию).

```py
while True:

    json_result = request.read_data()

    loadJob = client.load_table_from_json(json_result, table) 
    loadJob.result()
    
    if not has_more_data():
      break
```

Проблема в том, что изначально в схему для поля `nm_id` записалось `INTEGER`, а поле по факту должно быть `STRING`.

Пробовала задать схему по умолчанию для таблицы BigQuery

```py
      bigquery.SchemaField("realizationreport_id", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE"),
      bigquery.SchemaField("suppliercontract_code", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
      bigquery.SchemaField("rrd_id", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
      bigquery.SchemaField("gi_id", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE"),
      bigquery.SchemaField("subject_name", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
      bigquery.SchemaField("nm_id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"), #integer
      bigquery.SchemaField("barcode", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),#integer
      ...................
```

Кусочек JSON объекта:

```json
{
"realizationreport_id":5200242,
"suppliercontract_code":null,
"rrd_id":4681869162,
"gi_id":3246258,
"subject_name":"\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b",
"nm_id":44185221,          <--- serialized to INTEGER but should be STRING
"barcode":"2010739265043"  <--- serialized to INTEGER but should be STRING
........
}
```

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
                schema = wb_options.get_schema(),  # схема указана в примере выше              
                autodetect = False
                )

loadJob = client.load_table_from_json(json_result, table, job_config=job_config)  
loadJob.result()
```

получаю ошибку:

```
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Could not convert value to string. Field: nm_id; Value: 44185221
```

К слову, 'barcode' тоже переводится в INTEGER , хотя значение заключено в двойные кавычки

Google bigquery API при записи json в таблицу делает следующие шаги (предполагаю, могу ошибаться)

1. сначала переделывает json  в  newline-delimited JSON string (https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/66b3dd9f9aec3fda9610a3ceec8d8a477f2ab3b9/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L2710)
2. перекладывает временный файл в свое облако (https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/blob/d0827725085ab064169cda004a4fde65e92813f0/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py#L348)
3. делает запрос к сервису и записывает ответ в таблицу BigQuery
   `json.dumps(metadata).encode("utf-8")` (исходя из https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/blob/d0827725085ab064169cda004a4fde65e92813f0/google/resumable_media/_upload.py#L480)

возможно есть способ подставить `decoder` в `metadata`, чтобы конкретный ключ "nm_id" принимал тип STRING?

Так же не совсем понимаю, что такое `metadata`, изначально это  `bigquery.LoadJobConfig` переделанный в map. То есть теоретически я могу добавить `cls=JsonDecoder` в `metadata`?

Или надо как-то извернуться с настройками `bigquery.LoadJobConfig` ? (настройка `decimal_target_types` не подходит, т.к. сначала все равно переделает в NUMBER)

Спасибо , что дочитали

Очень жду помощи

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте детали: что в `wb_options.get_schema()` - там правильные типы? и последовать совету (Please look into the errors[] collection for more details) - после ошибки от `loadJob.result()`, посмотреть в `loadJob.errors`

Comment: @Michael Здравствуйте, обновила loadJob.errors. Поле nm_id должно быть STRING исходя из документации  сервиса откуда загружается объект json, однако приходит именно без кавычек. Поле barcode  в кавычках, но приводится к INTEGER.

Comment: думаю, это проблема с `"nm_id":44185221,          <--- serialized to INTEGER but should be STRING`
BigQuery не читает такое как строчка (ошибка в BigQuery). Со следующей строчкой, где число в кавычках, проблем быть не должно. Нет возможности добавить кавычки?

Comment: @Michael следующая строчка barcode тоже переводится в INTEGER (тестировала, если autodetect оставить ), хотя значение в кавычках. Файл  может приходить достаточно большой. Может можно как-то сериализовать значение конкретного поля, переопределить класс json.JSONEncoder и потом указать в metadata cls=NewJsonDecoder? Я пыталась в этом направлении искать, но застряла на том, как  определить это конкретное поле, чтобы его значение сериализовать.  "BigQuery не читает такое как строчка (ошибка в BigQuery)" - можете дать ссылку на ошибку?

Comment: тут разные проблемы:
1) когда значение это число в кавычках, как barcode - его autodetect распознает как число. Но если вы передаёте свою схему, где этой колонке присвоен тип STRING - BigQuery её нормально прочитает как строку. Укажите в своей схеме для barcode STRING, и всё будет в порядке.
2) если значение поля это число без кавычек, как nm_id - то BigQuery его умеет читать только как число. Если в этой колонке всегда числа без кавычек - читайте как INTEGER, потом конвертируйте. Иначе придется добавить кавычки или загружать другим способом (скажем CSV)

Comment: @Michael Спасибо за ответ. Поняла про autodetect. Придется подправить схему таблиц. Нашла еще подтверждение ошибки на похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json/32468017#32468017